# How to separately track master and remote configuration files?

Tags: git

I have a remote repository in a different directory structure than the master. A configuration file with pathnames on the master is tracked. When I pull from the master I'd like not to copy this file since the paths are different on the remote. But I'd like to also track the remote's configuration file on the remote.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classically, you would version:

- a template configuration file
- a value configuration file (one with a different name for each environment: repoA.config, repoB.config, ...)
- a script able to build the actual (and "private", because "not versioned") configuration file, based on the current environment.

That way, you can track the evolution of those settings in your local repo while getting a separate history for the remote repo settings.